# How is a basis induced on a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, change-of-basis, dual-spaces

I'm studying the concepts of the tangent and cotangent space, and I'm wondering how bases are induced, and what that means concretely. I feel like I have an intuitive guess as to what it means, but how do coordinates in the tangent space induce a basis set there? How is that rigorously established? Is there a general way that components allow you to deduce what a basis set on any vector space will look like? Further, how does a basis in the tangent space induce a basis on the cotangent space? Again, I feel like I intuitively understand why the basis is the differential, but I don't know how to derive it for things to click in my head.

Comment: Given coordinates, i.e. an isomorphism $T:V\to\Bbb R^n$, the preimage of the coordinate basis on $\Bbb R^n$ yields a basis of $V$.

Comment: This answers part of my question @ anon. In terms, I guess, of how a basis between vector spaces can be found. How would the basis of the tangent space be induced from its coordinates, though?

Comment: Take the derivative of a coordinate chart to get an isomorphism $T_xM\to\Bbb R^n$